# Default Dot is not showing in tooltip chart.js line type with labels

Tags: chart.js, tooltip, legend, dot

I have multiple line type charts in charjs. All is good but It is showing dot with label in the tooltip like I have in legends. I have added multiple options in the tooltip object but no one is working. Below is the image of the chart I got and it can be seen in the tooltip that it is missing dot in tooltips. I know it is a basic question but I am new to chart.js

[image]

```
 const newChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: {

        bezierCurve: true,
        lineTension: 0,
        responsive: true,
        showTooltips: true,
        layout: {
          padding: 20,
        },
        scales: {

          y: {
            border: {
              display: false,
            },
            suggestedMin: 30,
            suggestedMax: 80,
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              steps: 10,
              stepValue: 5,
              max: 100
            },
            grid: {
              color: darkMode ? gridColor.dark : gridColor.light,
            },
          },
          x: {
            type: 'time',
            time: {
              parser: 'hh:mm:ss',
              unit: displayYear ? 'year' : 'month',
              tooltipFormat: displayYear ? 'YYYY' : 'MMM DD',
              displayFormats: {
                second: 'MMM DD YYYY',
              },

            },
            ...MinMax,
            bounds: 'ticks',
            border: {
              display: false,
            },
            grid: {
              display: false,
            },
            ticks: {
              autoSkipPadding: 48,
              autoSkip: false,
              maxRotation: 0,
              beginAtZero: true,
              color: darkMode ? textColor.dark : textColor.light,
            },
          },
        },
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: true,
            fillStyle: "white",
            labels: {
              usePointStyle: true,
            }
          },
          tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            usePointStyle: true,
            titleFont: {
              weight: '600',
            },
            callbacks: {
              label: (context) => context.parsed.y,
              labelPointStyle: (context) => {
                return {
                  pointStyle: 'triangle',
                  rotation: 0
                };
              }
            },
            titleColor: darkMode ? tooltipTitleColor.dark : tooltipTitleColor.light,
            bodyColor: darkMode ? tooltipBodyColor.dark : tooltipBodyColor.light,
            backgroundColor: darkMode ? tooltipBgColor.dark : tooltipBgColor.light,
            borderColor: darkMode ? tooltipBorderColor.dark : tooltipBorderColor.light,
          },
        },
        interaction: {
          intersect: false,
          mode: 'nearest',
          axis: 'x'
        },
        animation: {
          duration: 2000,
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
      },
    });
```